# Algorithm time complexity

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

Supposing I have an **insertion-sort** algorithm with a cost function $8n^2$ and a **merge-sort** algorithm with a cost function $64n\log_2n$, for which n values is better to execute the **insertion-sort**?

I've tried doing $8n^2<64n\log_2n$ and found $2<n^{\frac{8}{n}}$ but I can't seem to find a way to properly isolate n. Is this result satisfactory?

Answer (score 1):

Use standard Calculus methods to sketch a graph of $f(n) = n^{8/n}$.
$$  f'(n) = -8n^{-2 + 8/n}(\ln(n) -1)  $$
We find a critical point at $n = \mathrm{e}$, so expect a maximum at $n = 2$ or $n = 3$.  Further, $f$ is monotonically increasing on $(0,\mathrm{e})$ and monotonically decreasing on $(\mathrm{e},\infty)$.  Also,
$$  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n) = 1  \text{,}  $$
so $f$ is initially less than $2$, is greater than $2$ on an interval, then is forever after less than $2$.

We should explicitly check $n = 1, 2, 3$:
\begin{align*}
f(1) &= 1^{8/1} = 1  \text{,}  \\
f(2) &= 2^{8/2} = 16 \text{, and}  \\
f(3) &= 3^{8/3} = 18.720{\dots}  \text{.} 
\end{align*}

So restricting $f$ to the positive integers, it has a maximum at $n = 3$.  It then decreases.  We perform (initially) unbounded binary search to find where $f$ decreases through $2$.

\begin{align*}
f(6) &= 10.90{\dots}  \text{,}  \\
f(12) &= 5.24{\dots}  \text{,}  \\
f(24) &= 2.88{\dots}  \text{,}  \\
f(48) &= 1.90{\dots}  \text{,}  \\
f(36) &= 2.21{\dots}  \text{,}  \\
f(42) &= 2.03{\dots}  \text{,}  \\
f(45) &= 1.96{\dots}  \text{,}  \\
f(43) &= 2.01{\dots}  \text{, and}  \\
f(44) &= 1.98{\dots}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
We find that $f(n) > 2$ for $2 \leq n \leq 43$.

Comment: Instead of exponentiating to get the final inequality, we can stop when at $$n < 8 \log_2 n,$$ which is a bit easier to work with. I decided not to make it a separate answer, though, since the technique ends up being about the same.

Comment: I will add that $n < 8 \log_2 n$ strongly suggests probing using powers of 2, rather than strict bisection. It's clear that $n=2$ works and $n=2^8=256$ does not. From there, trying $n=2^7, 2^6, 2^5$, etc., you quickly find that it's between $32$ and $64$. From there, proper bisection can take over.